# Follow Ups / Results

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

A lot of questions on this sight are very compelling to parents ( at least me ) who may be in a similar situation that another person has already completed.

I have no idea how this would work, but it would be awesome if somehow there was the ability to follow up / share results.

The best thing about StackExchange sites is the structural integrity of the format, and I wouldn't want to mess with that, so it would have to be well thought out - but if there was some mechanism that rewarded sharing results, I think it could be a real boon for later viewers.

This seems especially important on this site, but would probably provide value on any of the SE sites - or at least most.

Right now I think the closest opportunity to do this is the comments, but they don't have the same impact (I assume by design) as the questions and answers.

Comment: Are you referring to the OP's experience or any user's (e.g. respondents) experience?

Comment: @anongoodnurse - Good question.  I suppose that probably just the OP would be best.  Though as I said, I have no idea how it should look.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way this happens on most SE sites is for the OP to post an answer themselves - not to edit it into the question, as this generally breaks the Question and Answer process.

It is absolutely acceptable, and even encouraged, to answer your own question. There is even a check box for it when you ask a question to see whether you want to answer it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the standard way to share what worked is to edit one's question with the subsequent results.  The main difficulty is that it requires significant effort on the part of the question asker.

On some stack exchange sites, people tend to check an answer only after it works, limiting themselves to an upvote when an answer seems good but hasn't been tested yet.  That might be a good way of handling it here too.

Comment: The problem here though, is that mostly I want to know the results from the OP.  That is why I am proposing some structure where they are rewarded for following up that is distinct than the reward they get for posting a good question.  They are after all different things.

Comment: It's permitted for the question asker to post an answer; upvotes to such an answer might be a good reward mechanism that wouldn't be too exploitable.  The question is how to make this socially acceptable or expected.

Comment: `The question is how to make this socially acceptable or expected.`  Agreed.